# Hidden status bar shows white background

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uikit, statusbar

I have been trying to find a solution for hours but haven't had success.

So I'm using this code to "move up" a navigation controller during a full screen presentation

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
//viewController.navigationController.view.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
//viewController.view.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

//[viewController.view setNeedsDisplay];
NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(viewController.view.frame));
NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(viewController.navigationController.view.frame));
```

The results of the logs are as follows:
{{0, 0}, {320, 548}}
{{0, 0}, {320, 568}}

As you can see on the commented parts... I have tried some ways to fix the problem. However it seems like UIKit does not want to update the screen positioning.

Now if I execute this code after hiding the status bar and after a delay of let's say 0.2 seconds... it works as expected. However I can see per a moment the white space instead of the status bar.

What is weird, is that after this code has been executed once, there are no problems later even without delay. It only happens the first time.

So I need some help here... don't know what else to try. Any suggestions would be great, Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you set your views' .autoresizingMask to UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight ?

Comment: Yes they are. It works fine... but not the first time

Comment: did you already solved this?